# I can not Install debug Apk from build folder, Blocked by play protect

Tags: android-install-apk

I have been trying to copy debug Apk from my App Build folder(App->Build->Output->Apk) and trying to install to the device but I am getting error message while installing "Blocked by play protect".

But when I Sign my Apk with my debug KeyStore and **I can install successfully without this error** for a very first time but again When I generating APK with same debug keystore for the same APk I am facing the same issue that is **Blocked by play protect**.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Nothing is wrong with your apk. The warning is prompted becquse the apk is not signed. You can disable Play protect by following this [tuto](https://beebom.com/what-is-google-play-protect-enable-disable/) and everything will work fine.

> You can find the option to enable or disable Google Play Protect in the same Settings -> Google -> Security -> Google Play Protect page, where you will find options “Scan device for security threats” and “Improve harmful app detection“.

Comment: I am facing same issue. When i run from android studio working fine but when I'm trying to install from from apk directory it shows blocked by play protect. Is it ok or it's an issue?

Comment: @Rakeshkushwaha It's OK

Comment: i have also tried with signed apk but not wokring. So it's also ok?